# C++ overloaded operator declared as a friend

Tags: c++, templates

I declared an overloaded operator as a friend in an Xcode C++ program

```
template <typename T> friend class list_template;
template <typename T> friend ostream& operator<< (ostream &, list_template<T> &);
```

It gives me an error on the second declaration that list_template has not been declared?

If I #include the file where list_template is declared I get more problems...

Comment: Well, have you declared (and defined) `list_template`? The first line also seems to be a friend declaration. What is that good for anyway?

Comment: The error message is that list_template has not been declared, there is another message that says expected , or ... before <

Comment: When I asked for the error message, I wanted to see the actual error message, not your interpretation of what it means.

Comment: @melpomene 'list_template' has not been declared in file included from main.cpp 'list_template' has not been declared in node.h

Comment: @user9352 You should add that info to the question, not to a comment. Besides, as melpomene says, please copy the exact error message and tell us where are you writing those two lines or code. Are they inside a class? Are they together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a global forward declaration of list_template, if I understand what you're trying to do:

**MyClass.h**

```
// forward declarator. must match definition in list_template.h
template<typename T> class list_template;

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass() {};
    virtual ~MyClass() {};

    template<typename T> friend class list_template;
    template<typename T> friend ostream& operator <<(ostream&, const list_template<T>&);
};
```

**list_template.h**

```
template<typename T>
class list_template
{
public:
    list_template() {};
    virtual ~list_template() {};

    // declare friend ostream operator <<
    friend ostream& operator << <>(ostream& os, const list_template<T>& lt);
};

// ostream insertion operator <<
template<typename T>
ostream& operator <<(ostream& os, const list_template<T>& lt)
{
    // TODO: use lt here.
    return os;
}
```

At least I *think* this is near where you were going.